# Explanation for: $\frac{u^{-2}}{v^{-3}} = (u^{-2})(v^{-3})^{-1} = u^{-2}v^{3}=\frac{v^{3}}{u^{-2}}$ needed

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, exponentiation

I am just working through some sample problems in a introduction to discrete mathematics.

And i encountered this problem:

Task: Express in the simplest possible form, with positive exponents

Concrete problem: $\frac{u^{-2}}{v^{-3}}$

So normally when i attack this sort of algebra thing, i do:
$$
\frac{\frac{1}{u^2}}{\frac{1}{v^3}}
$$

And then i would for example multiply the fraction with $v^3$

$$
 \frac{v^3\frac{1}{u^2}}{v^3\frac{1}{v^3}} = \frac{v^{3}\frac{1}{u^{2}}}{1} = v^{3}\frac{1}{u^{2}} = \frac{v^{3}}{u^{2}}
$$

And then i guess i wouldn't simplify it more than that, but didn't give it more thought beyond that.

But in the book i think they want me to use the rule:
$(ab)^{x} = a^{x}b^{x}$, without explicitly saying so, because in their solution they do:
$\frac{u^{-2}}{v^{-3}} = (u^{-2})(v^{-3})^{-1} = u^{-2}v^{3}=\frac{v^{3}}{u^{-2}}$

Can anyone explain what the logic is behind their way of doing it? and can their result even be considered a positive exponent? it has a $u^{-2}$ as a denominator.

EDIT, add picture of solution in book:
[image: Picture of solution in book]

Comment: $u^{-2}v^3=v^3/u^2$

Comment: Does that mean that they made a typo in the book? i added the actual picture from the book.

Comment: Yes, the book is wrong.

Comment: oh okay, thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments. The book has made a mistake in the last line. I believe it should read:

$$\frac{u^{-2}}{v^{-3}}=(u)^{-2}(v^{-3})^{-1}=u^{-2}v^3=\frac{v^3}{u^2}$$